# How to use waf to build multiple Python packages?

Tags: python, waf

I am looking for using **waf** as a meta-build solution for orchestrating the build of multiple python packages. These packages do already have working build scripts (bash) which tests and produce `artefacts` (python source tar.gz and wheel files).

Still, the produced packages are inputs (dependencies) for some of the other ones and I want to be able to fully build the product and when one dependency is changed, it should be build and after this, all dependencies that consume it should also be rebuild.

I tried to find some examples related to python but I wasn't able to find any of them. Because the built files do contain the package version it makes harder to use them. If anyone has an example it would be helpful for getting a quick start.

Comment: You should be more specific about your difficulties. waf is very good at tracking dependencies, and your problem does not seems specific to python